# What tool can draw such a graph?

Tags: data-modeling, graph-databases, modeling

I need it on Linux or Mac. Especially it allows me to label the edges with words (i.e. HAS_ADDRESS). Also, the simpler, the better the tool.

Please see the attachment.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work for you, but it has the boxes and you can label the arrows or not, take a look at the screenshots. It's a great tool and also free :)

[CmapTools](http://cmap.ihmc.us/)